# make div NOT go off the top of the page

Tags: css

I have a DIV that pops up in a set position via a jQuery function when you mouse over an image, there are quite a few of  these vertically (say 1800px in total height)

The problem is that if i go down to the bottom of the page and mousover, the div appears too far up (out of the browser).

How can i get that div to not flow off the op of the page? IE stick to the top, instead of going off>

Comment: And we are supposed to imagine your code, or what?;p Put a link to jsFiddle!

Comment: Please include some of the code (JS, HTML, CSS) that demonstrates the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting to position it relative to the view port and not the page, is that correct?

If so, you need to use `position:static` on your element.

Comment: not as such no, i want it to hold its position within the page, UNLESS it is being forced outside the "viewport".

Comment: @DarkcatStudios you will have to use JavaScript to achieve that. If I have time, I will update my original to reflect what you're asking for.